# JavaScript-How can I add an onClick function to a dynamically created button element?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dynamically-generated

Beginner programmer here-I am making an app that generates list items with a dynamically created button as a child of the 'li' element. I want to assign an onClick function to this dynamically created button but nothing seems to work. I have tried many ways, here is my most recent code.

```
var done = document.createElement("button");
    done.onClick=function() {
        alert("working");
    };
    done.innerText = "Finished!";
    done.id = "deleteButton_";
```

The button generates fine but nothing happens when clicked. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

case matters

```
done.onClick=function() {
```

needs to be

```
done.onclick=function() {
```

better if you use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and not all browsers support innerText look into [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Answer (score 0):

For use **addEventListener**, you could do something like

```
done.addEventListener('click', function (){
    alert('working');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'buttonDiv';
var button= document.getElementById('buttonDiv').innerHtml('<input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)"');

function myFunction(button){
console.log(buton.id);
alert('pressed button with id :'+button.id);
}
```